# Where should the wiki for JS promises be written?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The tag for [promises](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/promise/info) is generic to computing, not specifically to JS promises. However, there is a real need to write a wiki, since many questions could be quickly answered with a link to the wiki.

Where should the wiki be written? Should a new `js-promises` tag be created? This sounds like a bad idea, but I'm not sure what else is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the list of questions : They're *all* about promises in JavaScript.

I don't know if there's a language other than JS (and derivatives) where this concept is commonly designed with this name. The usual term for the generic language-agnostic concept is *future* and there's a [future](/questions/tagged/future) tag.

I think we could decide that the [promise](/questions/tagged/promise) tag is about promises in JavaScript and change the description and wiki accordingly.

Comment: This may be the case today, but from what I found the term is also used in [R (promise objects)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) ([2 questions tagged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise+r) and [C++ (std::promise)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) ([18 questions tagged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise%20c%2b%2b))

Comment: How about being clear on which language it talks about? And eventually having multiple sections for languages.

Comment: @Stijn I didn't knew the C++ library. You should make another answer.

Comment: @dystroy I'm no expert in C++ (not even a novice) so I'd rather have someone with C++ experience chime in with an answer. For all I know, *promise* is not the industry standard term.

Comment: so way not rename the tag, to js-promises